# How to format time in "h m s" format in swift using `Duration.TimeFormatStyle`

Tags: swift, time-format

I wrote an extension of `TimeInterval` which returns a string in the format "h m s". For example, 5 hours, 33 minutes and 15 seconds would be written as "5h 33m 15s". This is the code:

```
extension TimeInterval {
  init(hours: Int, minutes: Int, seconds: Int) {
    self = Double(hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds)
  }

  func toString() -> String {
    let totalSeconds = Int(self)
    let hours = totalSeconds / 3600
    let minutes = (totalSeconds % 3600) / 60
    let seconds = totalSeconds % 60

    if hours >= 1 {
      return "\(hours)h \(minutes)m"
    } else if minutes >= 1 {
      return "\(minutes)m \(seconds)s"
    } else {
      return "\(seconds)s"
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to achieve this same functionality using Apple's `Duration.TimeFormatStyle` fashion. For example,I can do the following:

```
let style = Duration.TimeFormatStyle(pattern: .hourMinuteSecond)
var formattedTime = Duration.seconds(someInterval).formatted(style)
```

which I think is better practice than writing a `toString()` function as an extension of `TimeInterval`, but I'm not sure how to go about creating this style. Any guidance would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `Duration` `UnitsFormatStyle` units with narrow width:

```
let duration: Duration = .seconds(15 + 33 * 60 + 5 * 3600)
let string = duration.formatted(.units(width: .narrow)) // "5h 33m 15s"
```

Comment: Note that this only shows non-zero units. Adjust as needed.

Comment: @HangarRash OP asked for guidance. That's what I have posted.

Comment: I didn't mean anything negative. Simply pointing out a non-obvious detail for the OP (or future readers). If someone wants a a result of, for example. "5h 0m 15s" for an interval of `15*3600 + 15` then this answer, as currently written, won't give that result. If someone does want "5h 15s" then this answer is fine.

Comment: @HangarRash I don't think he can achieve the exact same behavior as the extension posted in the question. I will leave to the OP the decision about the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`units`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/duration/unitsformatstyle/units(allowed:width:maximumunitcount:zerovalueunits:valuelength:fractionalpart:)) format style.

From your `toString` code, it seems like

- you only want to display the units hours, minutes and seconds
- show no more than 2 units at a time
- even if a unit is 0, show "0" as well

Therefore, you can pass these options to `units`:

```
let formattedTime = Duration.seconds(someDuration).formatted(
    .units(
        // by default, the allowed units are hour, minute and second
        width: .narrow, // for the h, m, s unit names
        maximumUnitCount: 2, // show no more than 2 units
        zeroValueUnits: .show(length: 1) // show 0s as "0"
    )
)
```